# want names inside list to be as names of files using for loop python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a list below as list of names and want to use it as files names using loop.

```
name = [tina, vans, john, sam, victory]
```

using for loops i want to open files list below

```
for i in name:
   a=open('tina.txt')
   b=open('vans.txt')
   c=open('john.txt')
   d=open('sam.txt')
   e=open('victory.txt')
```

sorry i know this is not correct code but i want to do something like this for my code to be.
Can anyone please help me to get it right. THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (assuming that the scope of 'a' ends after each iteration, let me know otherwise):

```
for i in name:
    a = open(f'{i}.txt')
```

If you have a list of lists (as per your question in comments) you can do the following:

```
for i in name:
    for k in i:
        a = open(f'{k}.txt')
```

Comment: what if i have list inside list like this eg: name = [[tina, vans, john, sam, victory],[nanny, pink, sidewalk, paper, team],[jimmy, rob, stack, layla, london]]. How can i do the same thing using your code?

Comment: @Zac I added some solution for this too

Comment: what if i want to open all 5 files at the same time in 1st list inside the lists at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether that's what you're trying to do, but here something to start with:

```
names = ['tina', 'vans', 'john', 'sam', 'victory']
opened_files = []
for next_name in names:
    opened_files.append(open(f'{next_name}.txt', 'r')) # 'r' in case you just want to read
```

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you need this array:

```
names = ['tina', 'vans', 'john', 'sam', 'victory']
```

Then you can loop

```
for name in names:
    with open('{name}.txt'.format(name=name), 'r') as file:
         # do something
```

Comment: what if i want to open all 5 files at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

```
name = [tina, vans, john, sam, victory]
```

You can iterate over the list using for loop. Then, you can use `f-strings` to open the file.

```
for new in name:
    with open(f'{new}.txt','a') as file: 
        #some.code
```